# ¿se puede concatenrar variable+i con un for

Tags: kotlin

por ejemplo tengo 10 imágenes con id, he puesto 10 variables de la forma siguiente:
img1
img2
img3
img4
img5
img6
img7
img8
img9
img10

pregunto, como puedo hacer de un `for` recorra las variables?, en otros lenguajes yo he visto que lo saben poner así:

```
for (i in 1 .. 10){
   img+i.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

algo así pero en `kotlin` eso no es válido, me pretuntaba si a lo mejor es de otra forma que se hace, o simplemente no se puede, muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Para concatenar puedes usar `"${img} ${i}"`

La propiedad `.visibility` no es aplicable para la `i` en este caso

Comment: Es mejor esperar a que la pregunta sea clara antes de responder.

Answer (score 0):

gracias a todos ya encontre una solucion que es la siguente:
variables en general

```
lateinit var img1: ImageView
    lateinit var img2: ImageView
    lateinit var img3: ImageView
    lateinit var img4: ImageView
    lateinit var img5: ImageView
    lateinit var img6: ImageView
    lateinit var img7: ImageView
    lateinit var img8: ImageView
    lateinit var img9: ImageView
    lateinit var img10: ImageView
```

dentro del  onCreate:

```
 img1 = findViewById(R.id.img1)
        img2 = findViewById(R.id.img2)
        img3 = findViewById(R.id.img3)
        img4 = findViewById(R.id.img4)
        img5 = findViewById(R.id.img5)
        img6 = findViewById(R.id.img6)
        img7 = findViewById(R.id.img7)
        img8 = findViewById(R.id.img8)
        img9 = findViewById(R.id.img9)
        img10 = findViewById(R.id.img10)

 var imagenes = mutableListOf(img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7,img8,img9,img10)

 var con = uris.size

            for (i in con  .. 9){
                Log.d("holamundito", "variable img"+i.toString()+ " esta oculta")
                imagenes[i].visibility = View.GONE
            }

            for (datos in 0 until con){
                imagenes[datos].visibility = View.VISIBLE
                imagenes[datos].setImageURI(uris[datos])
            }
```

y listo funciona bien, pongo el codigo por si una persona le puede ayudar.